# Le son [æ] existe-t-il en français ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Je croyais que non, jusqu'à ce que j'écoute des chansons de Yelle, où (il me semble) [æ] apparaît comme allophone de /a/ dans, par exemple, *chaque* ou *caches*. Ecoutez sur [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QOxKCKC09A).

Est-ce que c'est mon imagination ? Est-ce que c'est commun aux dialectes de la France, ou est-ce que ça trahit une origine géographique particulière de cette chanteuse ?

Comment: Juste histoire de savoir rapidement à quel son vous faites référence, pourriez-vous indiquer le moment (minutes:secondes) où l'on peut l'entendre dans cette video?

Comment: 0:52 pour « chaque », et 2:09 pour « caches » ; personnellement, il me semble que ce sont des `/a/` prononcés normalement (ni `/æ/`, ni `/ɑ/`).

Comment: Est-ce que ça ne serait pas dû à la ligne mélodique qui comporte 2 notes pendant que les paroles restent sur une seule syllabe ("cha-aque") ? Du coup on a un "a" qui débute sur une note et se traîne pour se prolonger sur une autre, donnant l'impression d'un [æ] ?

Answer (score 3):

Le son `[æ]` *seul* n'est pas usuel en français, il n'est associé à aucun [phonème voyelle](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_graphies_des_phon%C3%A8mes_du_fran%C3%A7ais#Voyelles). En particulier, les mots d'origine étrangère qui l'utilisent ont tendance à être déformés en `[a]`, par exemple *smash*.

Ce son peut néanmoins être présent dans la variante nasalisée du phonème `/ɛ/` (Wikipédia [mentionne](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aPrononciation/fran%C3%A7ais#Changements_historiques) le français parisien): la base vocoïde du phonème `/ɛ̃/` est parfois plus proche du son `[æ]` que de `[ɛ]`.

Comment: Tu as une référence pour la deuxième phrase ?

Comment: @Evpok: J'ai ajouté une référence et modéré un peu mon affirmation. Perso j'ai tendance a mélanger `[ɛ̃]` et `[æ̃]`, tout en gardant `[œ̃]` très distinct. Par exemple il me semble que ne prononce pas « sainte » comme « cette » + nasalisation (même si c'est très proche).

Comment: Si je m'écoute très attentivement, je tire parfois sur le [ɜ̃](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel), mais pas sur le æ̃.